# Realm Database nested objects

Tags: java, android, realm, android-database

I am just starting to apply `RealmDB` in my application. I have one question regarding nesting objects.

I have previous experience working with `Entity Framework`. There is one useful feature available in `Entity Framework` - mappings.

The problem is that I need to have nested object. Here is an example

```
public class SessionModel extends RealmObject {

    private UserModel userModel;
    private ExpirationDate expirationDate;
}
```

As you can see the members are not simple types, but classes instead. Therefore it is problematic to map them correctly.

I wonder if there is any way to use custom retriever or mapper to get collect all objects manually and return a model with all fields set.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Does https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#relationships help?